# Logs are not being generated in the application console post spring boot update

Tags: logging, slf4j

We have upgraded our spring boot microservice application from 3.0.2 version
to the spring boot 3.1.0 version.
**After the upgradation the console logs are not being generated.**
We have changed io confluent version from 7.3.1 to 7.4.0, apache poi xml version from 4.1.2 to  5.1.0, and aws java SDK from 1.11.560 to   1.12.477 version as part of the upgradation. We are using  the SLF4j api for logging.